# Flutter : handling multiple navigation screen in CupertinoTabScaffold

Tags: flutter, navigation, tabbar, cupertinotabbar

Hello I am new to Flutter and I am trying to implement a bottom tab bar with multiple navigation screen for each tab.

Here is my initial set up

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(home: HomeScreen(),
        routes: {
          Screen1.id: (context) => Screen1(),
          Screen2.id: (context) => Screen1(),
          DetailScreen3.id: (context) => DetailScreen3(),
          DetailScreen4.id: (context) => DetailScreen4(),
        });
  }
}
```

Here is my HomeScreen

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.book_solid),
            title: Text('Articles'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.eye_solid),
            title: Text('Views'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
          return Screen1();
        } else {
          return Screen2();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my screen1

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'screen1';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, DetailScreen3.id);
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Text('Screen 1',),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my screen3

```
class DetailScreen3 extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'screen3';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(),
      child: Center(
        child: Text('terzo schermo',),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The tabBar work ok and I am able to swap between the 2 tabs but I am not able to navigate from screen 1 to screen 3. When I tap on screen1 Center widget, the screen start to navigate but half way it stops and then the screen become all black...

Here is the error

> There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.
>   Within each subtree for which heroes are to be animated (i.e. a
>   PageRoute subtree), each Hero must have a unique non-null tag. In this
>   case, multiple heroes had the following tag: Default Hero tag for
>   Cupertino navigation bars with navigator NavigatorState#05492(tickers:
>   tracking 2 tickers)

I understand the problem is related to the hero tag of the navigation bar which must have a unique identifier. How should I fix this problem? should I assign an heroTag to all navigation bar???

Many thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved by setting the following properties for each CupertinoNavigationBar

```
heroTag: 'screen1', // a different string for each navigationBar
transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
```

Answer (score -1):

As an iOS developer, I tried flutter for the first time, this thing caused a black screen after jumping the page, and also troubled me for two days

```
heroTag: 'screen1', // a different string for each navigationBar
transitionBetweenRoutes: false,
```